# Find combination of numbers close to X

Tags: recursion, numbers, combinations, offset

Imagine you have a list of *N* numbers. You also have the "target" number. You want to find the combination of Z numbers that summed together are close to the target.

**Example:**

```
Target = 3.085

List = [0.87, 1.24, 2.17, 1.89]
```

**Output:**

```
[0.87, 2.17] = 3.04 (0.045 offset)
```

In the example above you would get the group [0.87, 2.17] because it has the smallest offset from the target of 0.045. It's a list of 2 numbers but it could be more or less.

**My question is** what is the best way/algorithm (fastest) to solve this problem? I'm thinking a recursive approach but not yet exactly sure how. What is your opinion on this problem?

Comment: Best as in simplest or fastest or...?

Comment: I'm looking for the fastest way

Comment: Any particular reason [0.87, 2.17] isn't closest? Because it's below the target?

Comment: oh I'm sorry! it was a mistake! it should be [0.87, 2.17]....

Answer (score 1):

This is a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). To solve it you would do the following:

```
def knap(numbers,target):
    values = Set()
    values.add(0)
    for v in values:
        for n in numbers:
            if v+n<(2*target):  # this is optional..
                 values.add(v+n); 

    for v in values:
        # find the closest item to your target
```

Essentially, you are building up all of the possible sums of the numbers.  If you have integral values, you can make this even faster by using an array instead of a set.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, I would start by sorting the list. (Use your favorite algorithm.) Then find the index of the largest element that is smaller than the target. From there, pick the largest element that is less than the target, and combine it with the smallest element. That would probably be your baseline offset. If it is a negative offset, you can keep looking for combinations using bigger numbers; if it is a positive offset you can keep looking for combinations using smaller numbers. At that point recursion might be appropriate.

This doesn't yet address the need for 'Z' numbers, of course, but it's a step in the right direction and can be generalized.

Of course, depending on the size of the problem the "fastest" way might well be to divide up the possible combinations, assign them to a group of machines, and have each one do a brute-force calculation on its subset. Depends on how the question is phrased. :)